# Genetically variable cells that through natural selection achieves evolution in a single individual

Tags: biology, xenobiology, genetics, genetic-engineering

I posted a question some time ago about how could genetic engineering design people that could adapt to changing conditions beyond what simple acclimatization or activation/deactivation of genes in a fixed genome could enable, and I don't think it sprouted a really satisfying answer but I ended up thinking about a possible solution recently that I want to share and see if it makes any sense at all.

So, hear me out, what if, hypothetically, it happens to exist genetic variability among the cells of a single individual (kinda like chymeras), and if for example, the skin cells get exposed to more sunlinght than the body can handle through acclimatization or activation/deactivation of genes alone, the cells that reproduce before dying get naturally selected in an increasingly competitive environment, so a person with a very ligh skin can become a person with very dark skin  after some time.

This is the most basic example that I can think of, and I am not that good at biology or anything like that so please don't get too hard on me, I just want to know if that could work, and if not, how could it work then, thank you.

Comment: A non-hypothetical consequence of this type of activity is the various forms of cancer.

Comment: The cells on the outside of the skin are already dead. You cannot operate natural selection on dead cells. And anyway, the cells which make up a healthy multicellular organism do not "compete"; their multiplication is regulated for the benefit of the multicellular organism as a whole. When some of the cells of a multicellular organism become competitive that is called cancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have invented T cell selection.**

1. T cells scramble the genes for their T cell receptor.  Here are your genetically variable cells in a single individual.
2. T cells are pruned back if their novel receptor does not work or reacts to self antigens.
3. A T cell clone is amplified if there is an antigen corresponding to that cell's receptor, suggesting a pathogen which that T cell variety can attack.
4. Each individual contains a T cell repertoire it has evolved itself according to its own internal conditions.

Marvel, reader!  **Genetically variable cells that through natural selection achieves evolution in a single individual**

It is very cool stuff, T cell biology.  Here is a little whiff from wikipeda.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_cell#Origin,_early_development_and_migration_to_the_thymus

> TCR development Main article: T-cell receptor A critical step in T
> cell maturation is making a functional T cell receptor (TCR). Each
> mature T cell will ultimately contain a unique TCR that reacts to a
> random pattern, allowing the immune system to recognize many different
> types of pathogens. This process is essential in developing immunity
> to threats that the immune system has not encountered before, since
> due to random variation there will always be at least one TCR to match
> any new pathogen.
>
> A thymocyte can only become an active T cell when it survives the
> process of developing a functional TCR. The TCR consists of two major
> components, the alpha and beta chains. These both contain random
> elements designed to produce a wide variety of different TCRs, but due
> to this huge variety they must be tested to make sure they work at
> all. First, the thymocytes attempt to create a functional beta chain,
> testing it against a 'mock' alpha chain. Then they attempt to create a
> functional alpha chain. Once a working TCR has been produced, the
> cells then must test if their TCR will identify threats correctly, and
> to do this it is required to recognize the body’s major
> histocompatibility complex (MHC) in a process known as positive
> selection. The thymocyte must also ensure that it does not react
> adversely to "self" antigens, called negative selection. If both
> positive and negative selection are successful, the TCR becomes fully
> operational and the thymocyte becomes a T cell.